# Can a PS/2 keyboard be converted to USB hot swap (plug)?

Tags: usb, hardware, keyboard

I have an old keyboard made in 1998, and I want to use it, but my computer does not have a PS/2 port.

I bought an adapter to convert the PS/2 of the keyboard to USB. I know PS/2 cannot hot swap.

But now I convert it to USB; can it hot swap now?

Comment: We don't know if your keyboard with PS/2 connectors supports USB with an adapter or not. Some do, some don't.

Comment: Why don't you try it? (I can't think of any sane reason it shouldn't be hot swappble.)

Comment: I worried it will break. My computer is Macbook M1.

Comment: Why will it break? It doesn't make sense, it is a keyboard not an usb killer.

Comment: if it breaks, it deserves to be broken for not meeting usb specs which are pretty robust... if you want to break something else, you can likely find or make a hub with fuses to protect.

Comment: btw, a lot of ps2 keyboards can be hot swapped. I do recall sometimes have to reboot because one got pulled out, but that stopped being the case (for me at least) around 2000, and I was pleasantly surprised to be able to just plug it back in and continue...

Answer (score 3):

The PS/2 standard is not made for hot-plugging. It was assumed that the keyboard is plugged in before the computer is turned on and not unplugged as long as it was running.

However, the limitation is on the computer side. If the keyboard was unplugged and plugged in again, the computer would often lose the connection. The only way to recover it, was to reboot the computer. It didn't break anything.

USB is made for hot-plugging, both electrically and software-wise. And for a PS/2 keyboard, the PS/2-to-USB adapter adds the hot-plugging capability.

You cannot damage you computer by unplugging and replugging the keyboard. It's electrically safe.

If you pull and reconnect the USB adapter from the computer, I'm sure the connection to the keyboard will be reestablished. If you pull the PS/2 plug from the USB adapter, it depends on your adapter if the connection is reestablished.

Comment: Yes but you don't know what kind of adapter the OP is using. Some keyboards in that era support both PS/2 and USB protocols, so you only need a dumb electromechanical adapter. If the keyboard supports only PS/2 protocol, you need a smart adapter with a processor that supports USB with computer and PS/2 with keyboard. In both cases USB will be hot-pluggable.

Comment: @Justme i'm fairly sure that all PS2 KBs are circuit compatible with all USB specs, just using a different pinout for USB as it's a different physical connection. Going from a USB KB to PS2 port is tricky, but going forward is baked into the spec.

Comment: @dandavis there is no spec that guarantees compatibility. These days keyboars chips support only USB with USB connector. In the 90s keyboard chips supported only PS/2 with PS/2 connector. There was a transition period where keyboard chips supported both protocols and had one connector and the other connection was supported via a simple connector adapter.

Comment: @Justme: i can take my old IBM clunker from the 80s (before USB), and use an AT>PS2 to a PS2>USB adapter and it works fine; explain.

Comment: @dandavis That's because your adapter is an active adapter, it has a microcontroller in it that does a conversion between USB and PS/2 interfaces. To the computer it looks like an USB HID keyboard, to the keyboard it looks like a PS/2 host interface controller. Some other adapters are purely passive electromechanical adapter plugs which require the keyboard to support both USB and PS/2 protocols.

Comment: @Justme it's just a wiring harness, no actives at all (round grey for older to old, purple for old to new). what you describe is exactly like a usb kb to ps2 port adapter, and indeed a vanishing number of keyboards can use those. I tried dozens of permutations a couple years back while trying to find keyboards that can be easily read from Arduino; older is better for that.

Comment: @dandavis your keyboard from 80s does not support USB, it is impossible that so old keyboard would work on an USB port with a wiring harness adapter. USB does not have backward compatibility to PS/2 protocol, and the electrical interface is incompatible too (3.3V differential half-duplex packets for USB data, 5V open-collector / open-drain interface for PS/2.